# 2012 dodge charger 5.7 automatic

Tags: dodge, electronic-control-module, charger

Installed new ecm and pcm already flashed by seller. Dash displays message "press clutch and press start button to start " car is automatic. No crank u0100

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest whomever did the flash for you didn't realize the PCM they sent you was for a standard transmission and didn't make the changes. I'd talk to them about making the changes or have them send you a different PCM which is actually for your vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might have been flashed incorrectly, or there might be something in the software you can update to tell it what setup this vehicle runs. Do you have a scan tool that can access OEM level info for Dodge?

Presumably it's not happy if you just press the brake pedal and try to start instead?